# Will having a SIM card plugged into an iPad affect multiplayer gameplay on Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My sister and I are unable to connect to each other's world. Is it because my sister has no SIM card inside her iPad, but I do?

Answer (score 2):

No, having a SIM card plugged in has no difference.

To connect to each other's world, make sure you are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: That's unless you're on a mobile connection :P

Comment: @aytimothy If you're on a mobile connection, it is more complicated to connect to each other's world. You would need to host a hotspot or similar.

Comment: "Yeah, I know." - I was assuming that the OP didn't know that.